# Does an adder care if inputs are signed or unsigned?

Tags: vhdl

I was supposed to design a 3-bit 2's complement adder, and so far I've mixed an matched positive and negative inputs and seem to be getting the correct output.  Is there anything any difference between an ordinary adder and a 2's complement adder?

First, I have designed the 3-bit adder (gate-level) I have since added the gates for the final carry out, so please ignore that.  Picture here:

[image: Valid XHTML]

Here is my code (I am aware that I could name my signals better).

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

    entity B_addr is port(
    A2,A1,A0,B2,B1,B0 : in std_logic;
    Cout,Sum2,Sum1,Sum0 : out std_logic
    );
end B_addr;

architecture B_addr_arch of B_addr is

signal net0, net1, net2, net3, net4, net5, net6, net7, net8, net9, net10, net11 : std_logic;

begin
    net0 <= A0 xor B0;
    net1 <= '0';
    net2 <= net0 and net1;
    net3 <= A0 and B0;
    net4 <= net2 or net3;
    net5 <= A1 xor B1;
    net6 <= net5 and net4;
    net7 <= A1 and B1;
    net8 <= net6 or net7;
    net9 <= A2 xor B2;
    net10 <= net9 and net8;
    net11 <= A2 and B2;
    Sum0 <= net0 xor net1;
    Sum1 <= net5 xor net4;
    Sum2 <= net9 xor net8;
    Cout <= net10 or net11;

end B_addr_arch;
```

The main question I supposed I'd like answered is whether this will suffice for 2's complement addition?

Comment: *Is there anything special needed?*  Your question is unclear. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), can you ask a specific question? How would you prove the operation it provides are correct for all inputs? Write a testbench and compare expected results. You can use composite values (arrays) for A, B and Cout, Sum2, Sum1, Sum0. Your previous use had a and b 3 downto 0 instead of 2 downto 0.

Comment: I am not allowed to use arrays, that's why it has been done this way. I revised my question.

Comment: Some adders care, some don't. 2's complement has different properties than other numeric representations like 1's complement, sign&magnitude in that respect.

Comment: It turns out that I figured out what I needed to do (after nearly 10 hours).  The inputs into the adder will already be 2's complement numbers.  The professor wanted me to sign-extend the 3-bit inputs before adding, which would yield the correct 4-bit 2's complement output.  I needed to add an additional full adder omitting the final carry out.  Of course, the code had to change to reflect the additional gates.

Comment: So it's actually a 4 bit adder (3 bit operands sign extended). Perhaps you should have shown your actual assignment narrative.

Comment: *Is there anything any difference between an ordinary adder and a 2's complement adder? Yes. See [Overflow Detection for Adders](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Comb/overflow.html). For 2'sC your carry is an overflow bit. In unsigned addition the carry bit gives you a 4th result bit. The different properties Brian alludes to is value order: 100, 101, 110, 111, 000, 001, 010, 011 or -4 to 3 for 2'sC, while 000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111 or 0 to 7 for unsigned representation. 2'sC won't sign extend negative results using carry out.

Comment: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qvgo3jz8odxtreu/b_adder.vhdl?dl=1) is a demonstration of why your adder wasn't adequate.